# Mapping wordcloud color to a value for sentiment analysis

Tags: python, colors, colormap, word-cloud

So I'm looking to see if there is a way to map the color of a word cloud to a value, or maybe even overlap two word clouds (one positive and one negative list) with the end result being a dark color for negative sentiment and a bright color for a positive sentiment like in the picture only this is random.

I'm not sure how you would assign the value because from what I see you either paste text or text with a frequency value but maybe the latter of two maps overlapped?

I was able to change the color to greens here by copying code from StackOverflow and adjusting the values. As far as I can tell it's just randomly assigned. I pasted that code just below

```
def green_color_func(word, font_size, position,orientation,random_state=None, **kwargs):
    return("hsl(100,100%%, %d%%)" % np.random.randint(1,51))
wordCloud.recolor(color_func = green_color_func)
```

below is a sample of my simple code, for clarity I removed stopwords, font path etc, mask and b3 is a dictionary of hashtags and a count frequency...maybe somehow with a colorfunc or recolor(self[, random_state, color_func, …])?...[image: This is the cloud I have right now]

```
wordCloud = WordCloud(font_path = font_path,width=1000, height=800,max_words=100,
                      random_state=21, background_color = 'white',
                      prefer_horizontal=1).generate_from_frequencies(b3)




plt.figure(figsize=(30,15))
plt.imshow(wordCloud, interpolation = 'bilinear')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show() 

wordCloud.to_file("bt3.png")
```

I'm fairly new to coding and Im stumped by this so I appreciate any insight, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this was asked a while back - and may no longer be relevant. 
However, if someone is looking to achieve the same thing, then this is the way to do it.

Assuming you have a

- list of words (`word`),
- their sentiment (`score`),
- and their frequency (`freq`)

in a dataframe like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Create a dataframe with the sentimental word list
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/text-machine-lab/sentimental/master/sentimental/word_list/afinn.csv')

# Generate the random frequency for each word, however, set the seed for reproducibility
rs = np.random.seed(42)
df['freq'] = np.random.randint(1, 100, df.shape[0])

print(df)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
           word  score  freq
0       abandon     -2    52
1     abandoned     -2    93
2      abandons     -2    15
3      abducted     -2    72
4     abduction     -2    61
...         ...    ...   ...
2457      yucky     -2    77
2458      yummy      3    57
2459     zealot     -2    25
2460    zealots     -2     2
2461    zealous      2    64
```

You could create a word cloud with colours mapped to their sentiments using the following code:

**Note:**

- positive words are green,
- negative words are red,
- and neutral words are grey.

```py
from wordcloud import WordCloud
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

class SimpleGroupedColorFunc(object):
    def __init__(self, color_to_words, default_color):
        self.word_to_color = {word: color
                              for (color, words) in color_to_words.items()
                              for word in words}

        self.default_color = default_color

    def __call__(self, word, **kwargs):
        return self.word_to_color.get(word, self.default_color)



# Create a dataframe with the sentimental word list
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/text-machine-lab/sentimental/master/sentimental/word_list/afinn.csv')

# Generate the random frequency for each word, however, set the seed for reproducibility
rs = np.random.seed(42)
df['freq'] = np.random.randint(1, 100, df.shape[0])

# Generate a word-frequency dictionary to import to the word cloud
text_freq_dict = dict(zip(df.word, df.freq))

# Generate word cloud from word-frequency dictionary
wordcloud = WordCloud()
wordcloud.generate_from_frequencies(frequencies=text_freq_dict)

pos_words = []
neg_words = []

# Categorize the words based on sentiment score, assign to appropriate list 
for word, sentiment in zip(df['word'], df['score']):
    if sentiment > 1:
        pos_words.append(word)
    elif sentiment < -1:
        neg_words.append(word)


# Create a dictionary containing the colours to be used for each sentiment list
color_to_words = {
    # green colour for positive words
    '#00ff00': pos_words,
    # red for negative words
    'red': neg_words
}

# Neutral words will be grey (with sentiment between -1 and 1 inclusive)
default_color = 'grey'

# Create a color function with simple groupded tones
grouped_color_func = SimpleGroupedColorFunc(color_to_words, default_color)

# Apply our color function to the word cloud
wordcloud.recolor(color_func=grouped_color_func)

# Plot the word cloud
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation="bilinear")
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image: Word cloud]

Please note that some parts of the code above were borrowed from the [wordcloud package site](https://amueller.github.io/word_cloud/auto_examples/colored_by_group.html).

Comment: Awhile back is an understatement but this is great and I just used it and modified it with the colors I needed for the project. Thanks!

Comment: Well I am glad it helped you - even after all these years :)

Comment: I was surprised that I couldn't find any other tutorials out there to do this in python. This solution is Brilliant however.